# input onChange not updating state in jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

```
const setup = (props = {}, state = null,initialState={}) => {
  const store = storeFactory(initialState);
  const wrapper = mount(
  <Router
     <Component {...props} store={store}/>
  </Router>
  );
  if (state) wrapper.setState(state);
  return wrapper;
};
```

```
test("Rendered email input and test valid", () => {
  const email = "";
  const wrapper = setup(null, { email });
  const emailInput = findByTestAttribute(
    wrapper,
    someId
  );
  emailInput.simulate("change", { target: { value: "email@email.com" } });
  console.log(wrapper.state('email')) //Empty ""
  expect(wrapper.state("email")).toBe("email@email.com");
});
```

wrapper.state('email') should have returned email@email.com but it is not updated.Any reasons?

Comment: What does your onChange function look like?

Comment: onChangeHandler = id => async event => {
    this.setState(
      {
        [id]: event.target.value
      });
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `id` in the simulated event:

```
emailInput.simulate("change", {
        target: {
          id: "your id here"
          value: "email@email.com"
        }
      });
```

Also since updates are done asyncrhonously you should await your promises before performing any assertions.

Define a `flushPromises` function:

```
function flushPromises() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}
```

Then await promises in your test:

```
test("Rendered email input and test valid", () => {
  const email = "";
  const wrapper = setup(null, { email });
  const emailInput = findByTestAttribute(
    wrapper,
    someId
  );
  emailInput.simulate("change", { target: { id: "your id here", value: "email@email.com" } });
  await flushPromises; // await for promises to return
  console.log(wrapper.state('email')) //Empty ""
  expect(wrapper.state("email")).toBe("email@email.com");
});
```

Comment: Not working..Don't know whether Router or store has something to do with simulate event.

Comment: Sorry @Ismael Padilla Unfortunately it's not working

Comment: I have changed my onChange to
onChangeHandler = event => { this.setState( { email: event.target.value }); } 
still it's not working